# Reverting in Git to a specific point

Tags: git, revert, git-revert

I have a branch called:

```
myBranch
```

It has a bunch of changes on it on checking into the server.  The revision I want to go back to is:

```
5b31ec198
```

What are the steps to get that from the server back to my local?

Comment: The answer depends on whether you want to temporarily bring back 5b31ec198 (e.g. to inspect some files) or whether you want to reset the myBranch branch so its contents is back to that of commit 5b31ec198.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to return your local working copy to the state it was in when commit 5b31ec198 was checked in, just go to the top directory of your working copy and use `git checkout 5b31ec198`.

If you have changes that haven't been checked in, you'll need to check them in first, or use `git stash save` to save them for later.